# Opensmile installation on ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

when giving the command:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS=‘‘-O2 -mfpmath=sse -march=native’’ CFLAGS=‘‘-O2  -mfpmath=sse -march=native’’
```

it shows me the following error:

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-mfpmath=sse'
Try `./configure --help' for more information
```

I used sse2 but yet it is not working. On opensmile installation guide it is written that this option is not supported by all compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell supports `"..."` and `'...'` (plain ASCII quotes) to quote words that contain spaces.

Your command uses fancy directional Unicode quotation marks, but not the usual `“...”` double quote ones, but the `‘...’` single quote version, twice: `‘‘...’’`.

The shell doesn't understand those quotes, which is why `configure` thinks you're trying to set `CXXFLAGS=‘‘-O2` and `-mfpmath=sse` is parsed as a separate option.

Fix:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS='-O2 -mfpmath=sse -march=native' CFLAGS='-O2  -mfpmath=sse -march=native'
```